# Greasemonkey jQuery - crossdomain, assigning html value to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, subdomain, greasemonkey

I've been wanting, and trying, to create a 'little' code snippet that will display the user's name on their avatar. The info is on a subdomain, so there's the cross domain issue. I've got it sorted out, and it works, but there's one thing that's bugging me.

I can't seem to assign the value that's in a html element to a variable, for whatever reason. Neither can I call a function, so I have duplicate code.

The load and execute snippet is from another SO question because @require kills the entire script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @grant       GM_xmlhttpRequest

// ==/UserScript==



var load,execute,loadAndExecute;load=function(a,b,c){var d;d=document.createElement("script"),d.setAttribute("src",a),b!=null&&d.addEventListener("load",b),c!=null&&d.addEventListener("error",c),document.body.appendChild(d);return d},execute=function(a){var b,c;typeof a=="function"?b="("+a+")();":b=a,c=document.createElement("script"),c.textContent=b,document.body.appendChild(c);return c},loadAndExecute=function(a,b){return load(a,function(){return execute(b)})};

loadAndExecute("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js", function() {
    var numNew = 0;
    var numOld = 0;
    if(localStorage) {
        $(".user").each(function(i,v) {
            var currentUser = $(this);
            var profile = $(this).data("userprofile");
            if(profile !== undefined) {
                if(localStorage.getItem(profile)) {
                    numOld++;
                    currentUser.append('<span style="position: absolute;">' + localStorage.getItem(profile) + '</span>');
                } else {
                    $.get('http://sub.domain.com/user/' + profile, function(data) {
                        numNew++;
                        currentUser.append('<span style="position: absolute;">' + $(data).find('.userNameContainer').text() + '</span>');
                        localStorage.setItem(profile, $(data).find('.userNameContainer').text());
                    });
                }
            } else {
                var profile = $("img", this).data("miniprofile");
                if(profile !== undefined) {
                    if(localStorage.getItem(profile)) {
                        numOld++;
                        currentUser.append('<span style="position: absolute;">' + localStorage.getItem(profile) + '</span>');
                    } else {
                        $.get('http://sub.steamcommunity.com/user/' + profile, function(data) {
                            numNew++;
                            currentUser.append('<span style="position: absolute;">' + $(data).find('.userNameContainer').text() + '</span>');
                            localStorage.setItem(profile, $(data).find('.userNameContainer').text());
                        });
                    }
                }
            }   
        });
        console.log('Loaded from localStorage: ' + numOld);
        console.log('Loaded from server: ' + numNew);
    }
});
```

Assigning

```
$(data).find('.userNameContainer').text()
```

to a variable does nothing, breaks the script even. Why?

-

Response example:

```
<div class="profile_content">
 <div class="profile_top">
   <div class="profile_user">
    <div class="userAvatar">
     <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="user_content">
     <div class="userid">
      <span class="userid">1234</span>
     </div>
     <div><span class="userNameContainer">Mave</span></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of response (data)?

Comment: Added the response example. It works perfectly, I just can't assign it to a variable and use that.